# Getting a unreported exception ParseExpcetion error trying to convert Date

Tags: java, swing, date

I am getting a unreported exception ParseExpcetion error trying to convert Date. Here is my code that is getting the error, I believe I have to use a try and catch block, but I am unsure of how to use it here.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.*;
public class JOptionQuestionTen
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert Date in Form MM/dd/yy");

DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);
String formattedDate = outputFormat.format(date);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, formattedDate);



}


}
```

Comment: Define "unreported"...

Comment: JOptionQuestionTen.java:12: error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);

Comment: Then catch it. Read up on exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to catch the exception that is thrown. Wrap the code that throws the exception (a good IDE helps here) in a try-catch like this:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
try{
   Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);
   String formattedDate = outputFormat.format(date);
}
catch(ParseException ex){
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception, and hopefully provide a different output message. E.g.:

```
String output;
try {
   Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);
   output = outputFormat.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
   output = "Can't parse input of " + input;
   // also probably a log.error(e)
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
```